# Add timestamp to sdterr?

Tags: bash, unix-timestamp, moreutils

I've a application launched by bash script. I redirected stderr and stdout to different files:

```
./app >> /home/user/logs/debug.log 2>>/home/user/logs/debug.err &
```

And I need to add a timestamp for stderr lines.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 3):

check this out

```
./app >> /home/user/logs/debug.log 2> >( while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done > /home/user/logs/debug.err )
```

Comment: I've a syntax error because I need to add '&' to the end of line to run in backgroud